# Sticky header jQuery addClass not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create sticky header but when I am scrolling down `jQuery` `addClass` function is not working I have also tried with `$(this)` but it is also not working. I am trying to add another class while scrolling but it is not working. I want to change the background `color` of the header 
this is my `HTML` code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var objectSelect = $(".myNavigation");
    var objectPosition = objectSelect.offset().top;
    if (scroll > objectPosition) {
      $(this).addClass("active");
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass("active");
    }
  });


});
```

```css
.active {
  background: #147cc4 !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top navbar-dark mb-4 myNavigation">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <form class="form-inline navbar-form" role="search">
          <div class="search">

            <span class="fa fa-search"></span>

            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">

          </div>
        </form>
      </ul>
    </div>


    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">

      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="logoFont">Hifzil</a>
        </li>

      </ul>

      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link">Donate</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link">Login</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link">Sign In</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

And this is the `css` class in which i have changed the background `colors`

Answer (score 4):

***Problem***:- In your case `$(this)` refers to `window` not `.myNavigation`.

***Solution :-***

```
$(this).addClass("active");
$(this).removeClass("active");
```

***Need to be:-***

```
objectSelect.addClass("active");
objectSelect.removeClass("active");
```

***Working snippet:-*** https://jsfiddle.net/7ko4k75t/

Answer (score 2):

The *conditional statement* behaves as expected, although consider using the `.addClass()` method with the variable `objectSelect` - which has *already defined* the element that will require the class change (`.myNavigation`).

`$(this)`, in *this* case, is being used incorrectly, in regards to the scope, `this` refers to the `window` defined in the *selector range* of the `.scroll()` method.

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

*Note: console logging added to demonstrate when state changes occur*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var objectSelect = $(".myNavigation");
    var objectPosition = objectSelect.offset().top;
    if (scroll > objectPosition) {
      $(objectSelect).addClass("active");
      console.log('this:',$(objectSelect).attr('class'));
    } else {
      $(objectSelect).removeClass("active");
      console.log('this:',$(objectSelect).attr('class'));
    }
  });


});
```

```css
.active {
  background: #147cc4 !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}

html {
  min-height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top navbar-dark mb-4 myNavigation">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <form class="form-inline navbar-form" role="search">
          <div class="search">

            <span class="fa fa-search"></span>

            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">

          </div>
        </form>
      </ul>
    </div>


    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">

      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="logoFont">Hifzil</a>
        </li>

      </ul>

      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link">Donate</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link">Login</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link">Sign In</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution on pure JS:

```
var
    head = document.getElementsByClassName('myNavigation')[0];

function stickyHeader() {
    if (window.pageYOffset > 150) {
        head.classList.add('active');
    }
    else if (window.pageYOffset <= 150) {
        head.classList.remove('active');
    }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    stickyHeader();
});
```